# Webservice in Ruby that calls Java code

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, web-services, jruby

I have a JRuby/Rails app that needs to get data from a system written in Java. I have already worked out how to call Java code from Ruby.

However, lets say that the Client object I need to create, starts threads, communicates with the internal system etc, and that the data is delivered asynchronously in callbacks.

Do I have to write a separate web service (that creates this Client) with a permanent connection to the Java system? In such a way that my Ruby/Rails code can call it synchronously. Or is it possible to write this asynch handler directly in Rails?

When multiple HTTP clients issue their GET's, I would of course have to connect to the Java system when the first client arrives. For the following clients, the data would already be there.

I realize what the proper solution would be, but I'm curious whether I can do it all in Rails.

I can (for now) live without the realtime updating of the webpage, as long as the data in the Java callbacks are stored "somewhere" so that the next HTTP refresh/GET can return it. Nest step would be SSE, Javascript etc.

I think I know how to create the Java web service, however I would rather keep the solution a bit simpler with fewer services.

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible for you to extend the java backend? Or do you want a pure ruby solution?

Comment: Not sure I understand? The Java system is a trading application without any other connections to the outside world. I just wanted to create some reports in JRuby/Rails and thought this was a neat way of accessing the data in that system.

Comment: Are you allowed to do changes to the java code? If so, I have a solution. 2 solutions to be precise.

Comment: Yes I have access to everything.

Comment: I guess I'm looking for a better integration between the Java system and the JRuby web service without having to write so much glue code.... The alternative would be to skip Ruby altogether and maybe use a Java Web Framework instead, it's just that I like Ruby....

Answer (score 0):

Since you also have access to the java code, I have two approaches to extend the java backend, in order to provide the data you want to use in your ruby frontend application.

### Use REST or a HTTP Service

Your ruby webservice could interact with the backend utilizing REST (or any other HTTP approach). This would result in cleaner and more reusable code. Since you're able to access the backend data with any client that is capable of HTML.

### Use TCP together with a little protocol

In this approach the clients have to connect to a TCP socket on the backend to send data back and forth. You have to write a little byte or string based protocol which you also have to parse. It's more complex than the first approach, but also more performat and you don't have to rely on external libraries (e.g. jersey, for REST). It also has all the advantages of the former approach, you can serve any client capable of network communication and socket handling.

Comment: It's sort of correct, but it would cause me to have to create a lot of duplicated glue code. The data is there (in form of Java callbacks when updated) and I want to present it on a Web page.

Comment: Then maybe this helps you https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby